# Android list with 'grayed out' items

Tags: android, listview

In Android, I want to present the user with a list.  When an item on the list is selected some action is performed, and this list item is no longer selectable.  It is also 'grayed out' or the like to indicate that it cannot be selected the next time the list is displayed.  I have seen the isSelectable() override in Adapter, but I believe this causes the item to be treated as a separator,  which causes visual problems.  And I have not found a way to 'gray out' an item.  Any ideas?  Thanks...

Answer (score 11):

As far as graying out an item.  I'm not sure if this is the best way, but it's what I do:

```
view.setAlpha(75);
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
```

I'm basically making the item transparent and then setting the background color to gray.  If you're reusing your list items you should also change them back to their original state if the condition is not met, i.e.:

```
view.setAlpha(255);
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

that is, if your original state was no transparency and the background color was white.

Comment: Note: the view has to be an Android View that supports setAlpha.  An example of one such View is ImageView.

Comment: setAlpha(float) for View class is available only from 11 API level.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha(float)

Comment: setAlpha has a range from 0 to 1. Values like 255 don't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

You need the view to be disabled. If you are creating the views just call .setDisabled(boolean) on the top view. Setting the list item to be disabled doesn't work very well in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution I am using.  I set up an OnItemClickListener for my ListView.  When an item in the list is clicked, I take the passed in View and call **setEnabled(false)** on it.  This will gray out the item.  However, subsequent clicks on this item will still call the onItemClick method.  So, you will need to check on each click if the item is enabled/disabled and act accordingly.